# I already did git add . but it won't commit

Tags: git

I already did these commands after I made some huge modifications in my app:

```
git status
git add .
git commit -m "deploying live with heroku"
```

but still it didn't commit as I see alot of untracked files that are color red

and also I see this after issuing that commit..

```
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:

..............< all these modules here

Untracked files:

......................
no changes added to commit
```

Comment: Possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5959010/still-untracked-files-even-after-using-git-add)...

Comment: Make sure you run `git add .` in the root directory of your project. It adds the content of the current directory.

Comment: I already did @axiac look at this https://pastebin.com/MDEEr8S5 for seeing the end part of the result of the git status after i did git add .

Comment: It is a line-ending problem. Windows uses two characters (`CR` and `LF`) to end the lines of text files, Git internally uses only `LF` (Unix line-ending style).

Comment: It could be solved by [configuring Git properly](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-coreeol) but I think it is better to avoid it. Nowadays most Windows text editors can handle files that use the Unix line-ending convention.

Comment: The first answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1967370/4265352) explains very well how it works.

Comment: Hey guys this is a private repository that I'm going to upload to, does this matter when deploying it all

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201754/discussion-between-thebast-and-axiac).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try following command to add untracked and modified files to staging index.

```
git add -A;
```

Comment: I get this fatal: unable to stat 'composer.': No such file or directory

Comment: check link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14161297/git-error-fatal-unable-to-stat-no-such-file-or-directory to resolve fatal issue.

Comment: Yeah there's a file that was named `composer.` which could be a big issue for git probably because it was named without a file name.

Comment: When I try to do like : 
`git rm "composer."  fatal: pathspec '.' did not match any files
`

Comment: can you print git status output if you are ok with it? If yes then only print relative path w.r.t root directory of project.

Answer (score -3):

Try these commandm It will work. 
Add your files into staging by this command     $ git add --a

```
$ git status -s
$ git add --a
git commit -m "Your Commit Message"
git push -u origin master
```

Comment: $ git commit -m "first heroku deploy"
On branch master
Untracked files:
................
.....
nothing added to commit but untracked files present
```

Comment: There is no such option as `--a`. You probably want `-a` but it doesn't help here. Also, `git push` is not related to the question and it doesn't help.

Comment: @axiac Apparently Git interprets `--a` as `--all`, I suppose because there's no ambiguity. The equivalent short form would be `-A`.

Comment: Exactly sir, i mostly used this. I told him